# Single word for "of my own accord"

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m trying to show that I performed a task solely for my own benefit.

For example,

> I did x of my own accord.

However, the *of my own accord* seems a bit too explicit: I am looking for a word that shows I did this task purely for myself. *Voluntarily* isn’t really appropriate, as it implies that I volunteered to do it for someone else.

Comment: I've found _unaltruistically_ on the internet, but I'd stick with your original (solely for my own benefit). By the way, 'of my own accord' means 'without being prompted / having to be prompted'.

Comment: How about "selfishly"?

Comment: Selfishly is usually used in malicious context

Comment: @user123144, Is the OP about "my own benefit" or "my own accord". For "accord" means you did it without having to be asked
.

Comment: @user123144 - Isn't "solely for my own benefit" the definition of "selfish"?

Comment: If the central idea you're trying to convey is "of my own accord," then you might consider the single word _autonomously_, which _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) defines (in its adjectival form, _autonomous_) as meaning, among other things, "undertaken or carried out without outside control" and "responding, reacting, or developing independently of the whole."

Answer (score 1):

> I did X for myself/ me.

This is how they usually put it.

You could try:

> I did it [egocentrically](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/egocentric).

But the first one sounds better to me.

Comment: Who's "they"?  :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez: I've been asking myself that exact question ever since I learned English!

Answer (score 1):

> [freewill](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/freewill) (adj)
>
> done of your own accord   of your own free will or design; done by
>   choice; not forced or compelled.

- “a freewill offering”
  **(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/freewill)**)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "purposefully".

However, there is a caveat. Although it can suggests you did x through your own free will, it doesn't guarantee that doing x was your own idea.

Answer (score -1):

To ***indulge*** is to perform solely for one's own benefit.